# limit user input

Tags: java, limit, user-input

I know I can check user input to match certain chars etc., but is there any way to limit user input while the user is typing?

e.g.: The user presses the <kbd>8</kbd> key on his keyboard, but this doesn't echo because only the numbers <kbd>1</kbd>–<kbd>4</kbd> are allowed. When the user presses <kbd>3</kbd> it does echo and the program proceeds.

Is this possible without using libraries (which I am not allowed to use)?

Comment: "Plugins"? Are you writing this in the context of an existing application framework, or is it just Swing?

Comment: I think I used the wrong words(I'm not english :), what I ment is that I can't import anything from Java.util, or anything else (just scanner of course)

Comment: At first you should explain what you are talking about, a Web interface (which framework?), console/command line input or a graphical user interface (which toolkit, plain AWT, Swing or SWT?), etc.

Comment: Java in eclipse, no GUI

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't do your homework for you

Comment: That's not what i'm asking, all I asked is if it is possible, not HOW I scould do this

Comment: @user3165926 Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

If you want to limit the amount of characters that can be entered then: First create a new class that extends PlainDocument and add a limiter:

```
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class JTextFieldLimit extends PlainDocument { //Added limited textfield so you can only enter one char
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3452547874756361487L;
    private int limit;

    public JTextFieldLimit(int limit) {
        super();
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public void insertString(int offset, String  str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (str == null)
            return;

        if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= limit) {
            super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
        }

    }
}
```

Now you can create a new textfield and add the limiter

```
JTextField field = new JTextField(1); //1 stands for a maximum of 1 character allowed to be entered in this text field
field.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        char c = e.getKeyChar();
        //if that character is between 1 and 9 then continue, else make the systems beep sound
        //so in your case, this should be 1 and 4
        if (!((c >= '1') && (c <= '9') || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
            getToolkit().beep();
            e.consume();
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps ;)

(this is with a textfield, but the event listeners can be added to a lot of things and global listeners do exists)